# How do I add something to each route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Is there an easy way to add a permanent string to *every* route in a Rails app, given that I already have quite a few resources specified and don't want to refactor all into a namespace?

Can I do something along the lines of

```
map.root 'myappnamehere'
```

and have that string appended to the beginning of all routes? I realise that this is not how I implement map.root normally.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[path_prefix](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html)?

Comment: You'll want to do map.with_options :path_prefix => "..." do |map| ... end to make it apply for all routes easily.